# Starting out with PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In order to introduce myself to PDEs, I decided to set up my own, and see if I can solve it. So, I started with this:

$$z = x^2 + y^2$$

And differentiated with respect to x:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2x$$

And the same for y:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2y$$

So now, I can equate both equations:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{1}{y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{1}{x}$$

Now, I have to reverse this process and solve them. I presume you set both sides to equal a constant, $C_1$ like so:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{1}{y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{1}{x} = C_1$$

So I can split these apart again and integrate:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = C_1y$$
$$z = \frac{C_1}{2} y^2 + f(x) + C_2$$

And similarly:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = C_1x$$
$$z = \frac{C_1}{2} x^2 + g(y) + C_3$$

Comparing the two equations, I see that $f(x) = \frac{C_1}{2} x^2$, $g(y) = \frac{C_1}{2} y^2$ and $C_3 = C_2$, so we can write the equation as:

$$z = \frac{C_1}{2}\left(x^2 + y^2\right) + C_2$$

Where the values of the constants can be found later.

So, is this the right way of solving PDEs or is my technique wrong?

Comment: Why should both sides of that equation be equal to a constant? If you're truly interested in learning PDEs, you should be working from a book on the subject.

Comment: As you can easily check, for every differentiable function $f$, $z=f(x^2+y^2)$ is a solution of your PDE. So what do you think, is your method correct?

Comment: @ProfessorVector Well after trying the same method on some other equations, no, it only works here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done in fact is applying the method of separation of variables which is one method among various others.

The PDE to be solved is :
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{1}{y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{1}{x} \tag 1$$
A form of separation of variables is : 
$$z(x,y)=F(x)+G(y)$$
$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=F'(x)$

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=G'(y)$

$$G'(y) \frac{1}{y} = F'(x) \frac{1}{x}$$

This can be equal for any values of $x$ ans any values of $y$ only if both fonctions are constant. That is why $ \quad G'(y) \frac{1}{y} = F'(x) \frac{1}{x}=C_1$ 
$$\begin{cases}F'(x)=C_1x \quad\to\quad F(x)=\frac{C_1}{2}x^2+\text{constant} \\G'(y)=C_1y\quad\to\quad G(y)=\frac{C_1}{2}y^2+\text{constant}\end{cases}
\quad\to\quad z(x,y)=\frac{C_1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)+C_2$$
That is what you found, in fact in "reinventing" a form of the method of separation of variables.

The method of separation of variables, on several variants, cannot solve all the kind of PDEs.
They are other forms of separation of variables and other methods that you have to learn to be able to solve more completely this PDE and to solve more complicated PDEs.

In the case of the PDE (1) above, $\quad z(x,y)=\frac{C_1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)+C_2\quad$ is a family of solutions, but not all the solutions. A more general solving leads to 
$$z(x,y)=\Phi(x^2+y^2)$$
where $\Phi(X)$ is any differentiable function. Among them, the fonction $\Phi(X)=X$ corresponds to the fonction used at your starting point : $z(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.

The arbitrary function $\Phi$ is determined according to some boundary conditions when they are specified in the wording of the problem.

For example, if in addition to the PDE (1), a boundary condition $z(x,0)=x^2$ is specified, then the unique solution is $z(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. But if another boundary condition is specified, for example $z(0,y)=\sin(y^2)$ the unique solution is $z(x,y)=\sin(x^2+y^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

When you equated the two ODE's (w.r.t. $x$ and w.r.t. $y$), you ignored the value $2$ completely.
Now the equation 
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac1y=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac1x$$
tells us that the two expressions, $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac1y}$ and $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac1x}$ are *equal to each other*, but it doesn't say that both these expressions are *equal to $2$*. Also by making both these expressions equal to $C_1$, you changed the value $2$ by $C_1$, which hence also replaces $2$ in the end result. So the above PDE when solved doesn't make the answer same as the initial values $\displaystyle{(C_1=2,\ C_2=0)}$, but you can get the start expression for $z$ by introducing **initial value conditions** that make the values for $C_1$ and $C_2$ equal to $2$ and $0$, respectively. I don't know how to derive IVC's for given expression (that's because I didn't ever bother to find the ODE of a function and then solve it to get what I already have). Yet, by inspection, I can easily say that the initial value conditions for the given problem are
$$z(0,0)=0,\ z(1,0)=z(0,1)= 1$$
By putting these IVC's in the expression,
$$z=\frac{C_1}{2}(x^2+y^2)+C_2$$
I get $C_1=2$ and $C_2=0$ and putting these values in the result, we obtain
$$z=x^2+y^2$$
which is the required answer.